# subset recursively a data.frame

Tags: python, r, dataframe

I have a data frame with close to a 4 million of rows in it. I need an efficient to way to subset the data based on two criteria. I can do this is a for loop but was wondering if there is a more elegant way to do this, and obviously more efficient. The data.frame looks like this:

```
SNP         CHR     BP          P
rs1000000   chr1    126890980   0.000007
rs10000010  chr4    21618674    0.262098    
rs10000012  chr4    1357325     0.344192
rs10000013  chr4    37225069    0.726325    
rs10000017  chr4    84778125    0.204275    
rs10000023  chr4    95733906    0.701778
rs10000029  chr4    138685624   0.260899
rs1000002   chr3    183635768   0.779574
rs10000030  chr4    103374154   0.964166    
rs10000033  chr2    139599898   0.111846    
rs10000036  chr4    139219262   0.564791
rs10000037  chr4    38924330    0.392908    
rs10000038  chr4    189176035   0.971481    
rs1000003   chr3    98342907    0.000004
rs10000041  chr3    165621955   0.573376
rs10000042  chr3    5237152     0.834206    
rs10000056  chr4    189321617   0.268479
rs1000005   chr1    34433051    0.764046
rs10000062  chr4    5254744     0.238011    
rs10000064  chr4    127809621   0.000044
rs10000068  chr2    36924287    0.000003
rs10000075  chr4    179488911   0.100225    
rs10000076  chr4    183288360   0.962476
rs1000007   chr2    237752054   0.594928
rs10000081  chr1    17348363    0.517486    
rs10000082  chr1    167310192   0.261577    
rs10000088  chr1    182605350   0.649975
rs10000092  chr4    21895517    0.000005
rs10000100  chr4    19510493    0.296693
```

The first I need to do is to select those `SNP` with a `P` value lower than a threshold, then order this subset by `CHR` and `POS`. This is the easy part, using `subset` and `order`. However, the next step is the tricky one. Once I have this subset, I need to fetch all the `SNP` that fall into a 500,000 window up and down from the significant `SNP`, this step will define a region. I need to do it for all the significant `SNP` and store each region into a list or something similar to carry out further analysis. For example, in the displayed data frame the most significant `SNP` (i.e below a threshold of 0.001) for `CHR==chr1` is `rs1000000` and for `CHR==chr4` is `rs10000092`. Thus these two `SNP` would define two regions and I need to fetch in each of these regions the SNPs that fall into a region of 500,000 up and down from the `POS` of each of the most significant `SNP`.

I know it a bit complicated, right now, I am doing the tricky part by hand but it takes a long time to do it. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you trying to implment a common algorthim? If not there are libraries that make these types of operations fairly easy (and fast) such as Pandas http://pandas.pydata.org/.

Comment: Well, I am trying to set a pipeline to apply everytime I deal with this kind of data. I know about pandas but my knowledge is not as big to write a script, could you help with that?

Comment: I'm happy to help but generally on SO we do write that much code. If you show me the for loop version than I can show you how to implement it in Pandas.

Comment: Thanks, I will do my best and try to post where I get so far

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a partial solution ir R using `data.table`, which is probably the fastest way to go in R when dealing with large datasets.

```
library(data.table) # v1.9.7 (devel version)


df <- fread("C:/folderpath/data.csv") # load your data
setDT(df) # convert your dataset into data.table
```

#### 1st step

```
# Filter data under threshold 0.05 and Sort by CHR, POS
  df <- df[ P < 0.05, ][order(CHR, POS)]
```

#### 2nd step

```
df[, {idx = (1:.N)[which.min(P)]
      SNP[seq(max(1, idx - 5e5), min(.N, idx + 5e5))]}, by = CHR]
```

#### Saving output in different files

```
df[, fwrite(copy(.SD)[, SNP := SNP], paste0("output", SNP,".csv")), by = SNP]
```

ps. note that this answer uses `fwrite`, which is still in the development version of `data.table`.  [Go here for install instructions](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Installation). You could simply use `write.csv`, however you're dealing with a big dataset so speed is quite important and `fwrite` is certainly [one of the fastest alternatives](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10505605/speeding-up-the-performance-of-write-table).

Comment: Thank you @eddi. That sounds right to me. Please feel free to edit my answer.

Comment: Thanks guys, it did the trick, @eddi is there a way to split the different regions or to add the columns `BP`, and `P` to your output?

Comment: @user2380782 one option is to extract indices and then subset from the original `data.table` - `df[df, {idx = ...; .I[...]}, by = CHR]$V1]`

Comment: Thanks @eddi and rafael for your help

Comment: @eddi, the code for saving the file does not keep the first column. Is it possible to keep it ?

Comment: sure, here's one option: `fwrite(copy(.SD)[, SNP := SNP],...`