# How to quote just a column with write.csv/table in R?

Tags: r, csv, quotes

I have this result with my data after a **write.csv in R**:

```
Last_Name,Sales,Country,Quarter
Smith,$16,753.00 ,UK,Qtr 3
Johnson,$14,808.00 ,USA,Qtr 4
Williams,$10,644.00 ,UK,Qtr 2
```

and I **want** this result (which is the original format of my data):

```
Last_Name,Sales,Country,Quarter
Smith,"$16,753.00 ",UK,Qtr 3
Johnson,"$14,808.00 ",USA,Qtr 4
Williams,"$10,644.00 ",UK,Qtr 2
```

because obviously I have some problems with amounts!

but I **don't want** :

```
"Last_Name","Sales","Country","Quarter"
"Smith,"$16,753.00 ","UK","Qtr 3"
"Johnson","$14,808.00 ","USA","Qtr 4"
"Williams","$10,644.00 ","UK","Qtr 2"
```

Any ideas?

Comment: What is the type of the sales column?

Comment: Try with `df1$Sales <- shQuote(df1$Sales)` and then write the csv with `quote = FALSE`

Comment: sales column is String and I can't change the format

Comment: `df1$Sales <- shQuote(df1$Sales)` doesn't work because it adds simple quotes and I need double quotes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try quoting the sales column by itself:

```
df$Sales <- paste0("\"", df$Sales, "\"")
```

Then call `write.csv` without quotes.  Or, you may specify which columns you want quoted in your call to `write.csv`:

```
write.csv(file="out.csv", df, quote=c(2))
```

Comment: `df$Sales <- paste0("\"", df$Sales, "\"")` works fine! but without the final space

Comment: `write.csv(file="out.csv", df, quote=c(2))` doesn't work properly because it also add quote to the header line :

Comment: I mean the whole header line.

Answer (score 2):

This is the default behavior of `data.table::fwrite`, which only quotes columns as needed (in your case, to disambiguate the internal comma of the `Sales` field):

```
library(data.table)
fwrite(y)
# Last_Name,Sales,Country,Quarter
# Smith,"$16,753.00 ",UK,Qtr 3
# Johnson,"$14,808.00 ",USA,Qtr 4
# Williams,"$10,644.00 ",UK,Qtr 2
```

I'm just writing to `stdout` for convenience, of course you can specify an output file as the second argument (`file`). You can also control this behavior with the `quote` argument; `"auto"`, works as follows (from `?fwrite`):

> When `"auto"`, character fields, factor fields and column names will only be surrounded by double quotes when they need to be; i.e., when the field contains the separator `sep`, a line ending `\n`, the double quote itself or (when `list` columns are present) `sep2[2]` (see `sep2` below).

As a bonus, of course, `fwrite` is [*way* (can be upwards of 100x) faster than `write.csv`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10505605/speeding-up-the-performance-of-write-table/36465497#36465497).

Comment: **Amazing**, it works fine!!! It solved my problem just with `quote="auto"`. I guess now that my initial data has probably been produced with `fwrite`.

Comment: It's probably going to be helpful for my work and I hope that it will be widely used. **Thank you!**