# A good way to store huge matrix in a text file in R

Tags: r, matrix, bigdata

> Alpha      0.000 1.000 2.000 3.000 3.000
> Beta       1.000 0.000 2.000 3.000 3.000
> Gamma      2.000 2.000 0.000 3.000 3.000
> Delta      3.000 3.000 3.000 0.000 1.000
> Epsilon    3.000 3.000 3.000 1.000 0.000

Usually, we can store the matrix in txt using write.table() in R. But it takes a very long time to store a matrix with 40000 rows and columns. Is there any more efficient way to store it?

Comment: The [`vroom`](https://vroom.r-lib.org/) package is a lot faster than `read.table`. That way you can probably stick to texte files. I would also expect that it is faster when you save your data as R object with `saveRDS()`.

Comment: There are some benchmarks in the following link indicating that fwrite from data.table is fast and writes ordinary text (rather than binary). https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10505605/speeding-up-the-performance-of-write-table