# Is there a way to efficiently convert an R object data.table around 13 GB to a readily compatible file like .csv?

Tags: r, data.table

I currently have a 400 million row by 8 column R data.table that is around 13GB. I have tried to use `write.csv` to no avail. Afterwards, I read here about someone using `SQLite`. However, even that didn't work. My main motivation is to convert it into something that can be easily read by Matlab, S-Plus, etc. Converting into .RData form is very efficient as it compresses it into 900 MB. Is there something similar, but that is more applicable to other programs? Thanks!

Comment: maybe `hdf5` ?  A few more details about the contents (e.g. is it entirely numeric/double or does it contain other data types?) might be useful.

Comment: What is the problem with `write.csv`? It fails or freezes? You could open a file connection and print rows by chunks of a few thousands. I doubt this will ever fail. You can put a `print` in the loop to get an idea of how long it will take. And when you are done writing the csv, zip it.

Comment: @flodel so you mean like a loop or opening a looped file connection?

Comment: What do you mean "to no avail" or "that didn't work"? Did they fail with an error? Take too long? Create too large of an output file?

Comment: To echo @josilber, what was the specific error when trying `write.csv` (you do know this operation will take some time, right?) and what didn't work from the SO answer that uses `RSQLite`?

Comment: the write.csv command would take forever. I was using an Amazon server with 244 GB of RAM and I stopped the process after 2 hours. I was wondering if there was an easier way.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12013953/write-csv-for-large-data-table-in-r