# Writing big data frames to csv in R?

Tags: r

I am extracting the data from the server in R. I want to export that data (data frame) to CSV. Since the data is very big, write.csv is taking too much time or throwing an error. Is there any way to write the data to csv faster?

Comment: Try `data.table::fwrite()`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [write.csv for large data.table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12013953/write-csv-for-large-data-table)

Comment: `fwrite` is the fastest way to write a data table to csv, available in `data.table` package. https://www.r-bloggers.com/fast-csv-writing-for-r/

Comment: From the server? If database server, consider keeping big data in a DBMS and not flat file.

Answer (score 0):

You could seperate your data in chunks and append them to your csv file one by one in a for loop.

```
write.table(chunk, file = "df.csv", sep = ",", col.names = F, row.names = F, append = T)
```